# incompatible with type id<NSTextFieldDelegate>

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am getting new warning on my old OSX app. I am using OSX 10.10 and I am not quite sure where the problem is. Can someone help?

The actual warning is Property type 'id is incompatible with type id inherited from NSTextField

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "HyperlinkTextFieldDelegate.h"

@interface HyperlinkTextField : NSTextField <NSTextFieldDelegate>

@property (assign) id <HyperlinkTextFieldDelegate> delegate; <--- warning showing up here
@end
```

The main implementation is

```
@interface HyperlinkTextField ()
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *hyperlinkInfos;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTextView *textView;

- (void)_resetHyperlinkCursorRects;
@end

#define kHyperlinkInfoCharacterRangeKey @"range"
#define kHyperlinkInfoURLKey            @"url"
#define kHyperlinkInfoRectKey           @"rect"

@implementation HyperlinkTextField
@synthesize delegate;
```

And the delegate file is

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @protocol HyperlinkTextFieldDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void) barLinkClicked: (id) sender;

    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTextField already *has* a `delegate` property, and it is typed as `id<NSTextFieldDelegate>`. Thus, your HyperinkTextField, which is a subclass of NSTextField, *inherits* this property, just as the error message clearly tells you. You cannot override this inherited property and type it as `id<HyperlinkTextFieldDelegate>` where that is a *different type*.

Comment: You can solve this, I think, by making HyperlinkTextFieldDelegate conform to  NSTextFieldDelegate, but I'm not certain of that. It might be better to give _your_ property a different name.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I was also thinking we should be able to solve this using the same name delegate. However, I did solve it by changing name. Its simpler. But if anyone knows if it is possible to solve using delegate name please let us know.